# Magento 2 - How to load image from theme in frontend?

Tags: magento2, theme

I uploaded the image **amazon-pay-ic.svg** to **THEME/web/images/**.

How can I load it in the frontend?
I tried `www.example.com/images/amazon-pay-ic.svg` but it does not work and shows the 404 site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<img src="{{view url="images/amazon-pay-ic.svg"}}" alt="test" />` inside PHTML templates, then flush full_page and block_html caches.

For HTML templates use this:

`<img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('images/amazon-pay-ic.svg') }" alt="test" />`

Comment: I try to show it on a .html page.

Comment: @Black I've updated my answer to include HTML templates.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to include it in a CSS file from the theme?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, do you mean include the SVG inside a CSS file? If so then something like `background-image: url('../images/amazon-ay-ic.svg')` should do the trick from a less file in the theme.

Comment: I see. That makes sense, thank you again! :)